# Spring actuator auditevents endpoint is not working in Spring boot V2.0.0.M7

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I was trying out spring boot actuator with milestone V2.0.0.M7.
Every endpoints(`/beans,/metrics,/loggers`) work except `/auditevents`.

I have added this property to `application.properties` file.

```
management.endpoints.web.expose=*
```

But `/actuator/auditevents` not working

Why is is this happening?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In M7, the `after` query parameter [is required](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/actuator-api/html/#audit-events). You haven't said what "not working" means exactly, but I would guess that you're getting a 400 response telling you that you request is bad.

A valid request made with `curl` would look something like this:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/auditevents?after=2017-11-30T04%3A54%3A40.25Z
```

Comment: Worked!! Thanks a lot!! Will this actuator work with `spring boot admin`?(I am asking since the urls are changed)